# Liferay portlet : autologin iframe

Tags: liferay

I am at a loss. I am supposed to write a Liferay portlet that embeds a web site whose URL is

```
https://1.2.3.4/cloud/org/myorg
```

(it's a vCloud director API).
I have absolutely no idea how to do that. First I tried writing an iFrame portlet in Liferay Developer Studio, but then I realized there was no way I could add the autologin part to the embedded site. 
Then I tried writing a new portlet using the portlet wizard of Liferay Developer Studio and adding an iframe tag in the view.jsp. I don't know how to autologin in the website this way either. 
If anyone can, help me. I am desperate.
Thanks
Marie

Comment: Can you look into Liferay's Iframe portlet's configuration..there you would find Authentication related setting. ? have you tried that?

Comment: Hi. I don't know where the configuration of Liferay's iFrame portlet is. Where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay already has OOB iframe Portlet. You need to login as portal admin in Liferay. From Add Application icon you add Iframe Portlet. On top Right Corner of Portlet there is configuration where you can specify your above url (i.e. login url with your desired authentication parameters).

Link for your reference http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe%20Portlet (this is older version of liferay But basic configuration is same.)